# How do I search files in specified destination and let them all showed in one Finder window on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, finder, file-search

I want to search all .xml files inside a specified folder (and its subfolders) `~/folder/` and make all the result showed in one window, what can I do?

I can search all files but don't know how to specify the range as a given folder and its subfolders.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few steps:

1. Open the folder in the Finder.
2. In the search box, type XML, and you'll notice in the popup menu in the "Kinds" section there is an "XML" option. Choose it.
3. Make sure that you choose the folder in the search location options. It's defaulted to "This mac" (can be changed in the "Advanced" tab in the Finder's preferences).

Comment: Great. But in the Advanced tab I can only set it to 'search current folder', so that's all I can set? I have to search the files from the current folder?

Comment: You'd have to open in the folder you want to search. Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to be able to use "Document Container" as a search criterion, then save the whole thing as a Smart Folder…

… unfortunately, it doesn't work :-(

Any search using Document Container returns no results [some people have reported it will work if the container is your iCloud Drive, but I can't even get that to work] - apparently someone forgot to hook it into Spotlight as a valid search term.